# Nested class with static property access issue from outside c#

Tags: c#, oop

i have one main class and with in this main class i have another class A. class A has few static property and when i tried to access those static property from outside but getting error....not being possible

### here is my classes structure

```
 public class EShip
{
    class Credentials
    {
        private static string _accessKey = "aaa";
        private static string _accessPwd = "xxx";
        private static string _accountNumber = "2222";

        public static string AccessKey
        {
            get { return _accessKey; }
        }

        public static string AccessPassword
        {
            get { return _accessPwd; }
        }

        public static string AccountNumber
        {
            get { return _accountNumber; }
        }
    }

    public static Credentials Credential
    {
        { get; }
    }
}
```

i try to expose that inner class by a main class property and from outside i try to do like

```
EShip.Credentials.AccessKey
EShip.Credentials.AccessPassword
```

it is not getting possible......suggest me good approach and why i am stuck. thnx.

Comment: Please don't make us guess the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `Credentials` is not public, therefore it's not accessible. Change that and you're able to do:

```
String key = EShip.Credentials.AccessKey;
```

[Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

Comment: do i need to make the Credentials class public. due to security reason i do not want to do so.....any way out?

Comment: You could create a wrapperclass that displays the values that should be visible in public

Comment: You have made your property public anyway. Apart from that, why do you make it static? That means you have only one account in your program.